# What is a good way to make a classified ad website?

Tags: web, content-management-system, ads, hardcode

I am undecided whether to use a Content Manangement System ( wordpress, drupal, joomla ) to build my own classified ads website like olx.com or craiglsit.
Is it good to make a it using a CMS
Or should I just hard code it on my own?
assuming I have good programming skills.

Comment: No matter how good of a developer you are, you almost always want to avoid to avoid re-inventing the wheel. The only argument for the latter is for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to see which achieve the most of what you want out-of-the-box, which reduces how much you have to tweak / code.

Wordpress is more for a blog so avoid that one.  Joomla provides a good framework, but would require quite a lot of coding to extend.

A quick google says that classified ads-specific Content Management Systems do exist, eg http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=345
Personally, I'd look into these.

Comment: thank you so much for this richard! this is exactly what i'm looking for. It saves me from a lot of stress! thank you so much!! all of the sudden im googling stuffs about classified scripts and im bombarding myself with too much info right now. and its too exciting for me right now. gotta test them scripts right away! thank you again cheer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can be used to create a very good classified Ads Website. [Here's an article that shows how to create a classifieds web site using wordpress](http://www.findbestwebhosting.com/web-hosting-blog/index.php/how-to-create-your-own-classifieds-site-using-classipress).

Talking about wordpress. It is misunderstood that Wordpress can only be used for blogging..It is not true. Here's an article that shows [alternative uses of WordPress other than blogging](http://www.findbestwebhosting.com/web-hosting-blog/index.php/10-alternate-uses-of-wordpress-other-than-blogs)